# A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property error when trying to focus an entry in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a xamarin.forms application and I got this error,I can't found a solution for this

```
public MyClass()
    {
            InitializeComponent();

            entry2.OnBackspace += backspaceEventHandler;
    }
```

In the backspaceEventHandler method I'm trying to write something like this

```
private static BackspaceEventHandler backspaceEventHandler = (sender, e) =>
    {
            entry1.Focus();
    };
```

and my entry1 tag is like this

```
<StackLayout>
    <entry x:FieldModifier="Public" x:Name="entry1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding entry1Text}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Here,It is showing error in entry1.Focus() statement,What is the reason for this and how can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: `backspaceEventHandler` is static,  I'm assuming `entry1` is not. A static member can't access an instance member without a reference to the instance.

Comment: @MichaelRandall,Yeah I've both of them in same class and I've tried by removing the static keyword also but it still showing the same error

Comment: @sujithkarivelil,entry1 is an normal entry defined in xaml page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of initializing `backspaceEventHandler` with a lambda expression, write it as a method, or remove it completely and simply initialize the event handler to the lambda directly.
Also, remove the `static` keyword - as I wrote in the comments - a static member can't access instance members without a reference to a specific instance.

Here are two versions of the code that should fix the problem:

```
public MyClass()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    entry2.OnBackspace += (sender, e) => entry1.Focus();
}
```

I'm not sure what's the signature of the event handler should be, but assuming `object sender, EventArgs e` there's the other option:

```
public MyClass()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    entry2.OnBackspace += BackspaceEventHandler ;
}

private void BackspaceEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    entry1.Focus();
}
```

Comment: ,Thanks for the reply ,I think in my case the second way doesn't work will try to do it in first way,
Thank you